# Laravel 5.2 separate tables for each user

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Here are the tables in my scenario

- user (user_id)
- user1_order
- user2_order
- user3_order
- user1_calcs
- user2_calcs
- ..........

I have my own reasons to have separate table per user (lots of data per user, lots of joins/queries in my app, separation of user data, user satisfaction)

Laravel has migration feature, so you have to create a migration that will create a table..

My question is, how would I use Laravel to my scenario? as I am not sure when user signs up, and I can not pre-generate user tables until a user signs up..

Any help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) (do not confuse it with Laravel Events) to run table creation tasks, for example you could run [custom artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-commands) directly [from your code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code).

This command could create migrations from prepared `stubs` and then run `php artisan migrate` command.

Comment: an example using my scenario would be a great help, though I just heading towards the documentation you provided...thanks for you help anyway

Comment: Well, almost everything is well documented. You probably want to look for more information about Eloquent Events (it's really easy to use and cool thing). Also, you may have some trouble with creating migations from stubs. You can look at my package: https://github.com/alexeymezenin/russianseoslugs  where `/src/Commands/CreateSlugMigrationCommand.php` runs `/src/SlugMigrationCreator.php` to create migration from stub at `/src/stubs/migration.stub` - I hope this example will be helpful.